# Curl too slow with big files, known solutions don't work

Tags: php, windows, apache, curl

I upload files with curl in php running on Windows Server 2008 (via POST), but it always only uses about 10% of the possible speed. I've tried every solution that I could find:

-Using HTTP 1.0

-Using another cURL version

-another PHP version

-Using another Apache, use XAMPP, use WAMP, use IIS

-Changing the buffer size

-edit the registry of windows (windows socket stack problem)

-use another server

-use other files

-use different scripts

As said I've used different versions of everything I can change. Windows server 2008 seems to be the problem, but I can't change it because it is a rented server paid for a year. I will now try it with a virtual apache system on the server but this isn't a good solution. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: How are you certain that you're only using 10% of the "possible speed" ? FYI the download speed is most of the times not equal to the upload speed. Also, if the host you're uploading to doesn't support that much (their download rate is low or limited) then you can't do anything about it.

Comment: I post to the servers via browser on the same machine and always get about 10X of the speed I get with curl.